# what sorting algorithm could be this one?

Tags: c, sorting

I am trying to use this sort algorithm, just I am asking if it is using the quick sort algorithm or another type of sort

```
void qsufsort(uint64_t *I,uint64_t *V,u_char *old,uint64_t oldsize)
{
  uint64_t buff[256];
  uint64_t i,h,len;

  for(i=0;i<256;i++) buff[i]=0;
  for(i=0;i<oldsize;i++) buff[old[i]]++;
  for(i=1;i<256;i++) buff[i]+=buff[i-1];
  for(i=255;i>0;i--) buff[i]=buff[i-1];
  buff[0]=0;

  for(i=0;i<oldsize;i++) I[++buff[old[i]]]=i;
  I[0]=oldsize;
  for(i=0;i<oldsize;i++) V[i]=buff[old[i]];
  V[oldsize]=0;
  for(i=1;i<256;i++) if(buff[i]==buff[i-1]+1) I[buff[i]]=-1;
  I[0]=-1;

  for(h=1;I[0]!=-(oldsize+1);h+=h) {
    len=0;
    for(i=0;i<oldsize+1;) {
      if(I[i]<0) {
        len-=I[i];
        i-=I[i];
      } else {
        if(len) I[i-len]=-len;
        len=V[I[i]]+1-i;
        split(I,V,i,len,h);
        i+=len;
        len=0;
      };
    };
    if(len) I[i-len]=-len;
  };

  for(i=0;i<oldsize+1;i++) I[V[i]]=i;
}
```

what I understood that it will count the occurrence of each character in an array of 256 elements

Comment: Maybe [radix sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort)?

Comment: @pmg the first lines seems to be a simple counting sort, but after that it diverges